# Canvas - Sticking png images together without taking into account transparent pixels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have big horizontal strip image in photoshop which is made of lots of smaller elements. The background is transparent and the strip goes from smaller elements (left) to bigger elements (right). My goal is to make this strip interactive to mouse events.

Each element is some kind of polygonal image which is trimmed left and right and then exported as a png. It is then imported into a canvas.

The problem is that I can put them side by side but since they are not rectangles I need a way to calculate the offset made up by the transparent pixels on each side of each element to make them stick together correctly... I am using **KineticJs** to get a precise hitarea for each element... So maybe there is a way to do it automatically with kineticjs,or there is some kind of operation I could do using each image data?

My problem illustrated:

[image: My problem illustrated]

Any ideas?

Also I am doing this simply because I would prefer precise mouseOver bounding box on each item (rather than a simple rectangle) and would rather avoid the solution to calculate each offset manually... But maybe that's not worth it?!

Comment: So the images are crazy shapes or just slanted like your illustration?

Comment: take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8Vdht/3/, there is no way of doing what you want built in with kineticjs, as all images are rectangles, you would have to just do the calculations yourself dependent on the image. If you have the calculations done, then you can code the logic.

Comment: @mattdlockyer : No crazy shapes, there are just at least two points (one on each side) that touch the borders..

Comment: @EliteOctagon : My problem is what would that calculation/logic be? =) But maybe it is just an overkill... And I am not really good at calculations!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have yourself a custom shape you want to use, here is a tutorial for that: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/ , the simplest thing you can do, and even that seems fairly long, is to calculate the bounding lines for that shape. (Two somewhat vertical lines, and two somewhat horizontal lines). Then you test if the right vertical line of shape one crosses with the left vertical line of shape two, if they do, then set the coordinates of the images to be the same coordinate.

http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html

```
line1 = ax + b ..... line2 = cx+d //see possible tests
if(...intersection test...){  // or just test if some coordinate is left of some other coordinate
    shape2.setX(shape1.getX()+shape1.getWidth()); //account for image width, so they don't overlap
    shape2.setY(shape1.getY()) // no need to account for height
}
```

UPDATE: This is a very rough solution to the workings of the problem. The next step would be to do more fine tuning dependent on each image.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jkr7/15/

Comment: if you can put together a jsfiddle with some temporary images which are not rectangles (the canvas will treat them as rectangles though), I might be able to help you some more.

Comment: Thank you! But it seems to get a bit complicated (even if it certainly is the right way to do!)... If I understand well, I would need to parse each image data (the shape is a bitmap), then get a mathematical representation of at least each side line (right and left), then do the math and reposition each element? That would be a lot a calculations...

Comment: Also I tried to put a [simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jkr7/6/) but as you can see I'm not that good at programming and there is a problem with the hitareas.. Maybe it's a problem with the image not being hosted on the same domain (canvas limitation with bitmap data manipulation?) or it's just me =) Thanks again!

Comment: I like the fiddle, but it doesn't work with kineticjs 4.3.1, even so, check my updated answer above.

Comment: Your fiddle works really fine but it still doesn't take into account the transparent pixels... And we may no go farther with jsfiddle since we can't manipulate canvas bitmap data (it throws a security notice). At last I think I will just go a simpler way, let go canvas and use square hitbox or image maps as said below. **Thank you** very much for your time and brain power!! Also I just modified your fiddle to make it clear we can move the different elements since I didn't notice it the first time! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jkr7/14/)

Comment: Well, you have to define the size of transparent pixels, here I used 10 pixels. http://jsfiddle.net/9jkr7/15/ What you would have to do is create a storage scheme so that each image has a stored has it's own individual distance of pixels of transparent data, and replace the 10 with it.

Comment: this might help if you're looking for image data: http://falcon80.com/HTMLCanvas/PixelManipulation/getImageData.html

Comment: Yes that would be the way to go with canvas but I was expecting some kind of simple **and** automatic way to do it but it seems we can't have the two at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want precise areas, use an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map).  With some clever finagling and a blank image gif you should be able to have the background you want whenever you hover over any particular area of the image map (might require javascript).

The other option I can think of would be to use SVG itself or one of the many libraries in existance to build interactive vector graphics into your page.

Comment: Yes, maybe if I can generate image maps automatically with an image editor that would be best... Otherwise I'll just stick with square hitboxes..

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a function that calculates the left most, top most, right most, and bottom most pixel by looking at all of the pixels in the image data.  Here's a tutorial on that:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that if you look at the second block in my picture above, I need to know what is the "top left" pixel of this block... but it's neither the top most or the left most pixel... so how would I know which pixel it is in the image data array? ... or am I missing something?

Comment: When I think about it maybe I could save the coordinates of the top most and bottom most pixel of the preceding block to get the first non zero alpha pixel at those coordinate in my current block... That would certainly be a good approximation I think, since my blocks are "growing" in a v shape manner... Is there another way?